# Not unique table/alias: 'siswa' Error Number: 1066 Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have eror in my scirpt, i just want to show siswa detail data

> Error Number: 1066
>
> Not unique table/alias: 'siswa'
>
> SELECT * FROM (`kelas`, `siswa`) JOIN `siswa` ON `siswa`.`kelas_id` =
> `kelas`.`id` WHERE `nis` = '1001'
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/konsultasi/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

My Controller :

```
public function siswa_detail($id)
  {
    $detail = $this->m_datas->detail_data($id);
    $data['detail'] = $detail;

    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('v_bk/view_siswa_detail', $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
  }
```

My Models :

```
public function detail_data($id = NULL)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('siswa');
        $this->db->join('kelas', 'siswa.kelas_id = kelas.id');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('siswa', array('nis' => $id))->row();
        return $query;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to delete `$this->db->from('siswa')`

```
    public function detail_data($id = NULL)
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->join('kelas', 'siswa.kelas_id = kelas.id');
        $query = $this->db->get_where('siswa', array('nis' => $id))->row();
        return $query;
    }
```

and It is good to insert 'left' or 'right' in join.

```
$this->db->join('kelas', 'siswa.kelas_id = kelas.id', 'left');
```